# Приведение типов

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Когда мы изменяем тип объекта,например так:

```
A b = (B) a
```

Что мы в итоге получаем: объект типа А или объект типа В? Постоянно возникает путаница.

Comment: эм, ну переменная "b" будет иметь тип А. Если хотите получить ещеинформацию, то сформулируйте вопрос по-другому

Comment: На научном языке - восходящее преобразование всегда безопасно, а нисходящее преобразование небезопасно. Нужно проверять/знать точный тип. Можете Брюса Эккеля почитать - книжку философия java - там разжёвано ну очень сильно

Answer (score 6):

Это называется приведение типов. На самом деле тип объекта изменить нельзя, но можно привести его к супертипу или подтипу. Привести к типу - это значит, что теперь с объектом можно обращаться как с экземпляром приведенного типа.

Например, если вы объявите коллекцию

`Collection collection = new ArrayList()`

то у вас будет переменная `collection`, у которой вы можете вызвать метод `add` (потому что он объявлен в интерфейсе Collection), но в итоге у вас будет вызван метод `add`, класса `ArrayList` (см. про позднее связывание и виртуальные методы). Но вы не сможете вызвыать метод `get`. Но не потому, что вы изменили тип объекта, а потому что в интерфейсе `Collection` данные метод не выставлен, а значит он недосутпен через переменную `collection`.

Теперь где-то в коде вы выполняете следующую операцию:

```
List list = (List) collection;
```

Заметьте, у вас все еще один экземпляр `ArrayList` (в памяти один объект), но на него теперь ссылаются две переменные, которые имеют разные типы: `Collection` и `List`.

К слову сказать, все упомянутые преобразования возможны, потому что `List` является супертипом для `ArrayList`, а `Collection` является супертипом для `List`. Если бы вы попробовали преобразовать `ArrayList` например к `Set`, то получили бы ошибку (на этапе компиляции или исполнения, зависит от кода).

Answer (score 2):

```
B link1=new B();
A link2 = (A) link1;
```

если допустить что "B extends A", то link1 будет иметь тип A и иметь возможность вызывать только методы класса A, но ссылаться будет на область памяти где хранится B(). Так же если в B переопределяются методы, то вызываться будут именно они...

это происходит потому что класс потомок одновременно является и классом родителя. В памяти они хранятся так

```
{{родитель}{потомок}}
{{A}{B}{C}{...}}//при наследовании A<-B<-C<-...
```

Answer (score 2):

Тип объекта от применения операции приведения типов (casting) - **не меняется!**

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно помню и если допустить, что класс В является наследником класса А, то получается, что объект b принадлежит к классу А.

Answer (score 0):

Мы получаем ссылку типа А на объект, а с сами объектом при этом ничего не происходит он остается того типа, конструктором какого класса он был создан.