# TreeSet и работа методов HeadSet, tailSet, subSet

Tags: java, коллекции

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<String> states = new TreeSet<>();

        states.add("Germany");
        states.add("France");
        states.add("Italy");
        states.add("Spain");
        states.add("Great Britain");

        System.out.println(states);

        // возвращаем набор в котором все элементы меньше текущего
        SortedSet<String> setLower=states.headSet("Germany");

        System.out.println("Это headSet " + setLower);

        // возвращаем набор в котором все элементы больше текущего
        SortedSet<String> setGreater=states.tailSet("Germany");
        System.out.println("Это tailSet " + setGreater);

        // получим поднабор от одного элемента до другого
        SortedSet<String> set = states.subSet("Germany", "Italy");
        System.out.println("Это subSet " + set);
    }
}
```

Начну с `headSet`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так мне отсортировало после добавления.

```
[France, Germany, Great Britain, Italy, Spain]
```

`headSet` отработал правильно, вот что я прочитал про этот метод:
Возвращает набор в котором все элементы меньше текущего

Вывело в консоль:

```
Это headSet [France]
```

Получается если у нас `Germany` на 2 месте, значит меньше него (текущего) только `France` потому что она на 1 месте? Поэтому и вывело France?

`tailSet`:
Возвращает набор в котором все элементы больше текущего

Вывело в консоль:

```
Это tailSet [Germany, Great Britain, Italy, Spain]
```

Получается метод tailSet выводит текущий элемент и те которые больше него? То есть у нас `Germany` на 2 месте, а `Great Britain` на 3, `Italy` на 4 и `Spain` на 5. Почему мы получили: [Germany, Great Britain, Italy, Spain], а не [Great Britain, Italy, Spain]?

`subSet`:
 Получим поднабор от одного элемента до другого

Вывело в консоль:

```
Это subSet [Germany, Great Britain]
```

Но я не понял почему? Мы же написали якобы от `Germany` до `Italy`, почему в консоли вышло `Germany` и `Great Britain`? Почему не только `Great Britain`?

Видел вот такую конструкцию:

```
SortedSet<String> setLower=states.headSet("Germany");
```

и вот такую:

```
`setLower.headSet("Germany");` ?
```

Почему сразу записывают в конструктор?
Ещё видел вот такие вещи:

```
Set setLower = states.headSet("Germany");<br>
```

В чем отличие такой конструкции от SortedSet?

Comment: Вы его так не пинганете

Comment: @AntonSorokin а как это сделать?)

Comment: Где Вы все это прочитали? Описание работы методов не сходится с [документацией](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) оттого и все проблемы с пониманием.

Comment: @defaultlocale если честно читаю на русском материал, в документации не очень понял :/

Comment: @defaultlocale https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/5.5.php

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван как вариант - в чате

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Описание работы этих методов в Вашем источнике не самое удачное.

В документации написано яснее:

[`SortedSet<E> headSet​(E toElement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#headSet(E)):

> Returns a view of the portion of this set whose elements are strictly less than toElement.  ...
>
> *Возвращает отображение части текущего множества, элементы которого **строго меньше** `toElement`*

[`SortedSet<E> tailSet​(E fromElement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#tailSet(E)):

> Returns a view of the portion of this set whose elements are greater than or equal to fromElement. ...
>
> *Возвращает отображение части текущего множества, элементы которого **больше либо равны**  `toElement`* ...

[`SortedSet<E> subSet​(E fromElement, E toElement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#subSet(E,E)):

> Returns a view of the portion of this set whose elements range from fromElement, inclusive, to toElement, exclusive. (If fromElement and toElement are equal, the returned set is empty.) ...
>
> *Возвращает отображение части текущего множества, элементы которого входят в диапазон от `fromElement` **включительно** до `toElement` **исключительно*** ...

В общем случае если указываются границы A и B (одна из которых может быть началом или концом коллекции), то имеется ввиду диапазон [A; B) (левая граница включается, правая исключается). С одной стороны это сделано просто потому что так принято, с другой — такое разбиение позволит «склеить» множество из частей не думая о границах отрезков.

Answer (score 2):

> `Set setLower = states.headSet("Germany");` В чем отличие такой
>   конструкции от SortedSet?

`Set` - это интерфейс, от которого произошли SortedSet, HashSet, и т.п. Вроде как такая конструкция - это полиморфизм. Одно из главных преимуществ такой конструкции - вы можете налету изменить тип вашей коллекции на другой:
`sortSet = hashSet;`.

Более подробно помогут разобраться эти вопросы:

[Чем отличается ArrayList ArList = new ArrayList();](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584846/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-arraylist-arlist-new-arraylist)

[Приведение типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/312412/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2)

[Как на практике применяется полиморфизм?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/935362/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC)

> Видел вот такую конструкцию:
>
> `SortedSet<String> setLower=states.headSet("Germany");` и вот такую:
>
> `setLower.headSet("Germany");` ? Почему сразу записывают в
>   конструктор?

Где вы увидели запись в конструктор? `states.headSet(...)` возвращает коллекцию с определенными элементами. `setLower` - теперь ссылка, которая ведет на эту коллекцию.

Про остальное - как уже [написали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944279/treeset-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2-headset-tailset-subset#comment1571401_944279), "описание работы методов не сходится с документацией оттого и все проблемы с пониманием". Если у вас плохо с английским - один из способов - скачайте расширение расширение для автопереводов, например [Google Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?hl=ru), и читайте английскую документацию.